# Asp mvc User Login using Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have created a sample project and have Azure server to maintain resources and security at same time. In my ASP web application i want to create Login system and i want it to protect using Azure security vault. Basically i want to store them in Azure vault. I have gone through understand of keys and secrets and Azure AD authentication using SDK in my web application but i am not getting understanding about making use of Keys/ Secret for User ID and Password that can help user to login into my application.

Should i save username or password of a user inside keyvault. If i am doing it then what is the purpose of getting these values because they are simply accessible through URL.

I tried looking for various examples but they were all using OWIN authentication using Social networking website but in my case I will be no social network login.

Looking for help to understand where how can i use of Azure key vault's Key/Secret in the context of securing user's login credentials. Any hint would be helpful.

Ref : Key Vault REST APIs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/

Comment: You can use Key Vault to store connection string but I am not if you can use it to store user info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store user credentials in Key Vault.
That is not its purpose.

If you store passwords, you need to store them in a database after hashing them securely.
Lot of emphasis on securely.
There should never be a way for you to recover a user's password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep the user information inside azure and use it in your application, what is need is Azure Active Directory. You can have a look at the [examples on how to implement AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp) in mvc project.

You use Azure Key Vault for the secrets that your program need or some secrets that you want to give access to a set or users. You don's use Azure key vault to store general user and password information. Hope this helps.